# ssh key errors when trying to connect a worker

Tags: concourse

I'm trying to set up concourse for the first time. I went through tutorials and was successful getting concourse running in vagrant and the hello world demo.  I want to know set up worker, for now this is all on my local machine, to do iOS builds. I can't seem to get the right ssh keys set. I keep getting:

````
{"timestamp":"1499972495.137019873","source":"worker","message":"worker.beacon.restarting","log_level":2,"data":{"error":"failed to dial: failed to construct client connection:%!(EXTRA *errors.errorString=ssh: handshake failed: remote host public key mismatch)","session":"3"}}```
````

I generated my local worker keys per the tutorial, and found the keys in the vagrant vm at `/opt/concourse`. However, any public keys I copy from the server for the TSA key don't seem to match what's expected.

Am I having trouble because I’m running the lite version from the tutorial?

Are the keys in `/opt/concourse` ones I want to use?

Comment: What is the file name of the TSA key you copied?

Comment: I skipped the vagrant install and went with the docker install. That tutorial got me thru the steps to generate the right keys for worker and TSA.

Answer (score 0):

I've had troubles as well with registering workers at the TSA, although in my case the error message was slightly different (`EOF` or `packet too large`). Since it is an SSH error, try to debug it step by step. I am not sure what your setup looks like, mine is as follows:

```
TSA    (from docker-compose) listening on 2222
Host   (runs concourse). 127.0.0.1:2228 maps to docker container on :2222
nginx  listening on 2222
Worker (on Windows, OS X, …) registers at TSA
```

Some of those pieces breaks SSH traffic, so try to log in on this port with SSH directly. Go step by step, first test on the host only (to see if you can access the docker container), then test from the worker (to see if you can get through nginx). For the above case

```
# On the host
ssh -i worker-key-path -p 2222 127.0.0.1 -v
# On the worker
ssh -i worker-key-path -p 2222 example.com -v
```

Note that the public key of the worker has to be known to TSA in the `authorized_worker_keys` file.

On a successful login, you should see

```
Authenticated to example.com ([12.34.56.78]:2222).
[...]
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
shell request failed on channel 0
```

If you see an error message like

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

then the nginx configuration is wrong, which should redirect with `stream`:

```
stream {
    server {
    listen 2222;
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:2228;
    #proxy_ssl on;
    }
}
```